# Count of field of 3 tables

Tags: ch

I have 3 table  EMPLOYEE,HOME,OFFICE

in Employee 2 fields available EMP ID,TAG ,Home has 2 filed Home ID,HTAG and office has 3 fields EMP ID,TAG,OFZname

EMPLOYEE

```
EmP ID  TAG
1       yellow
2      pink
3       green
```

Home

```
Home ID  HTaG
1        pink
2        pink
3        blue
```

Office

```
EMP ID TAG OFZname
1     blue mumbai
2     green  chennai
```

I want a query so that result is

```
pink 3
blue 2
green 2
```

by combining 2 table

Comment: try using returns and punctuation, maybe someone understands the question then.

Answer (score 0):

Posting query with punctuation would be better understandable to people who is going to help. Anyway...

Use `join` to combine two tables those have the information you need should be in join and get them with `select` and write a `where` clause with common field id.